# spring boot - neo4j - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm having a trouble with mapping an object `Employee` to my database when invoking a default method in my `Employee` repository. I get an argument type mismatch when invoking an `employeerepository.findall()` method

### Employee repository

```
package org.jarivm.relationGraph.repositories;

import org.jarivm.relationGraph.domains.Employee;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.domains.Project;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Jari Van Melckebeke
 * @since 10.10.16
 */
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends GraphRepository<Employee> {

}
```

### the controller

```
package org.jarivm.relationGraph.services;

import org.jarivm.relationGraph.domains.*;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.repositories.ClientRepository;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.repositories.EmployeeRepository;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.repositories.ProjectRepository;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.repositories.SectorRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Jari Van Melckebeke
 * @since 17.10.16.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
@Transactional
public class UserController {
    private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;
    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;
    private final SectorRepository sectorRepository;
    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository, SectorRepository sectorRepository, ProjectRepository projectRepository, ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.sectorRepository = sectorRepository;
        this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String userIndex() {
        return "/user/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/tableOverview")
    public String graph(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("graphClient", clientRepository.graph(150));
        model.addAttribute("graphProject", projectRepository.graph(150));
        return "/user/tableOverview";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/employeeByScore")
    public String employeeByScore(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("graphEmployee", employeeRepository.employeesOfAllTime(150)); //works
        return "/user/employeeByScore";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/newProject")
    public String newProject(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("projectToken", new Project());
        System.out.println(employeeRepository.count()); //works
        System.out.println(employeeRepository.findAll(50)); //fails???
        model.addAttribute("employees", employeeRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("employeeList", new ArrayList<WorkedOn>());
        model.addAttribute("clients", clientRepository.findAll());
        return "/user/create/newProject";
    }
}
```

### Project domain

```
package org.jarivm.relationGraph.domains;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.DateString;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Jari Van Melckebeke
 * @since 20.09.16
 */
@NodeEntity(label = "Project")
@Component
public class Project {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private Double cost;
    private Double scoreFromClient;
    private List<String> conflicts;
    private Long nConflicts;
    private String name;
    private String version;
    private String language;

    @DateString(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateStarted;
    @DateString(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateFinished;

    @Relationship(type = "Issued")
    private Issued issued;

    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Project() {
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCost(Double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public Double getScoreFromClient() {
        return scoreFromClient;
    }

    public void setScoreFromClient(Double scoreFromClient) {
        this.scoreFromClient = scoreFromClient;
    }

    public List<String> getConflicts() {
        return conflicts;
    }

    public void setConflicts(List<String> conflicts) {
        this.conflicts = conflicts;
    }

    public Long getnConflicts() {
        return nConflicts;
    }

    public void setnConflicts(Long nConflicts) {
        this.nConflicts = nConflicts;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDateStarted() {
        return dateStarted;
    }

    public void setDateStarted(Date dateStarted) {
        this.dateStarted = dateStarted;
    }

    public Date getDateFinished() {
        return dateFinished;
    }

    public void setDateFinished(Date dateFinished) {
        this.dateFinished = dateFinished;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public Issued getIssued() {
        return issued;
    }

    public void setIssued(Issued issued) {
        this.issued = issued;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", cost=" + cost +
                ", scoreFromClient=" + scoreFromClient +
                ", conflicts=" + conflicts +
                ", nConflicts=" + nConflicts +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", version='" + version + '\'' +
                ", language='" + language + '\'' +
                ", dateStarted=" + dateStarted +
                ", dateFinished=" + dateFinished +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### error log

```
2016-10-21 19:19:00.118 ERROR 30643 --- [nio-2904-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of org.jarivm.relationGraph.domains.Employee] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entity.io.MethodWriter.write(MethodWriter.java:40) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entity.io.MethodWriter.write(MethodWriter.java:70) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:234) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:186) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:162) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:145) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:120) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:85) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:75) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:112) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:151) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate.loadAll(Neo4jTemplate.java:100) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.loadAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:125) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.jarivm.relationGraph.services.UserController.newProject(UserController.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.jarivm.relationGraph.services.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b4c5dcbc.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.jarivm.relationGraph.services.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57d059d2.newProject(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at ...
```

thanks in advance,
Jari Van Melckebeke

Comment: Can you post the full error log?

Comment: org.jarivm.relationGraph.services.UserController.newProject(UserController.java:81)

Comment: Why did you edit out the respective method in `EmployeeRepository`? I believe it is crucial to see the query in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a first look, you return some properties that are not present in the `Project` class, e.g. `first_name` and `last_name`. This looks to me like you intended to return a `User` node as well? Also, you return `first_name` and `last_name` twice. Additionally, you return several String properties; how is Spring supposed to know which of them should be mapped to the Map index?

I suggest that you define something like this

```
public class ProjectWithIndexResult {
    private String index;
    private project Project;
    ....
}
```

and return `List<ProjectWithIndexResult>` instead of the Map.

Slightly off topic: It's not good code style to have variable names with underscores.

Comment: What do you mean with 'return', ok, I've forgot to edit the names in my querry, but, even with the change of `first_name` and `last_name` in my code, it will not work.