# Jersey @BeanParam, @HeaderParam alternatives in Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

In **Jersey** we can inject a list of headers to a model class using `@BeanParam` and `@HeaderParam`. Are there any alternatives in Spring MVC to do the same thing?

I know in spring-MVC, we can inject all headers to a map **`@RequestHeader Map<String, Object> headers**` and extract the fields from there. But I was wondering if I can inject my required headers into a model class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you cannot. You will have to do that in your code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement for `@HeaderParam` is Spring MVC's [@RequestHeader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html)

> The @RequestHeader annotation allows a method parameter to be bound to a request header.
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping
> public void displayHeaderInfo(@RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding") String encoding,
> ```

And `@BeanParam` you don't need special annotation, just add your bean to method as is:

```
@RequestMapping
public String displayHeaderInfo (MyBean myBean) {
```

Comment: Thanks. @RequestHeader for mapping a single header, Since I wanted to map a list of headers to a Bean and when I used your suggested approach `public String displayHeaderInfo (MyBean myBean) {`, I am getting exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

Comment: @pijushcse there's a problem with your bean. see example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181777/spring-boot-neo4j-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-argument-type-mismatch

Comment: @HeaderParam is applicable to field, but  '@RequestHeader' is not. What would be the proper replacement then? (Hi @pijushcse)